# ifstream operator >> and error handling

Tags: c++, iostream

I want to use ifstream to read data from a named piped. I would like to use its operator>> to read formatted data (typically, an int).
However, I am a bit confused in the way error handling works.

Imagine I want to read an int but only 3 bytes are available. Errors bits would be set, but what will happen to theses 3 bytes ? Will they "disappear", will they be put back into the stream for later extraction ?

Thanks,

Comment: `operator>>` will not read a (four-byte, or whatever) binary integer. It will read the textual representation of an integer.

Comment: Well, I guess that solves my question... Any advice on how I should handle that manually ? Can I use the putback() method to try again later if read() didnt read at least 4bytes? And if it did, create my int using those 4 bytes manually?

Comment: Indeed, that's what 'formatted' means in this context. If you want to read _binary_ data, that is 'unformatted input'.

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the 'formatted' here :). For me it was more like: please, create a int or w/e from the raw data you can read.

Comment: @ildjarn There's no such thing as "unformatted input".  All data has some format, and when reading, you have to respect the format. `istream` and `ostream` handle textual formatting.  There is no single widespread binary format, so the standard doesn't support any binary formats.  The usual solution is to write your own streams, e.g. `ixdrstream` and `oxdrstream`, if the binary format is XDR.  (This is a lot simpler than it seems.)

Comment: You can open the pipe in binary mode, read the binary data as it comes in, and when you have enough, send it to a parsing function.

Comment: @JamesKanze That may be, but the C++ standard defines two terms of art: *formatted input functions* and *unformatted input functions*. See C++ 2003 27.6.1.1/2: "Two groups of member function signatures share common properties: the *formatted input functions* (or
extractors) and the *unformatted input functions*."

Comment: @Robᵩ The data is formatted (unless its just random bytes).  The standard streams do have functions to read the underlying bytes (the _unformatted input functions_), but all that means is that it is up to you to do the parsing.  Until you've interpreted the data according to a specified format, it's just raw bytes.  Not data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out, you can't read binary data over an `istream`.
But concerning the number of available bytes issue (since you'll
probably want to use `basic_ios<char>` and `streambuf` for your binary
streams): `istream` and `ostream` use a `streambuf` for the actual
sourcing and sinking of the bytes.  And `streambuf` normally buffer: the
procedure is: if a byte is in the buffer, return it, otherwise, try to
reload the buffer, *waiting* until the reloading has finished, or 
definitively failed.  In case of definitive failure, the `streambuf`
returns end of file, and that terminates the input; `istream` will
memorize the end of file, and not attempt any more input.  So if the
type you are reading needs four bytes, it will request four bytes from
the `streambuf`, and will normally wait until those four bytes are 
there.  No error will be set (because there isn't an error); you will
simply not return from the `operator>>` until those four bytes arrive.

If you implement your own binary streams, I would strongly recommend
using the same pattern; it will allow direct use of already existing
standard components like `std::ios_base` and (perhaps) `std::filebuf`,
and will provide other programmers with an idiom they are familiar with.
If the blocking is a problem, the simplest solution is just to run the
input in a separate thread, communicating via a message queue or
something similar.  (Boost has support for asynchronous IO.  This avoids
threads, but is globally much more complicated, and doesn't work well
with the classical stream idiom.)